# Remove specific properties from JSON object

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have a JSON:

```
{
    "scbs_currentstatus": "",
      "scbs_primaryissue": "",
      "_umb_id": "Test",
      "_umb_creator": "Admin",
      "_umb_createdate": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
      "_umb_updatedate": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
      "_umb_doctype": "Test",
      "_umb_login": "Test",
      "_umb_email": "Test",
      "_umb_password": {
        "newPassword": "Test",
        "oldPassword": null,
        "reset": null,
        "answer": null
      },
      "_umb_membergroup": {
        " User": false,
        "Line User": true,
        "Callback User": false,
        "Su User": false,
        },
      "umbracoMemberComments": "Test",
      "umbracoMemberFailedPasswordAttempts": ""

    }
```

Iam trying to remove all the properties start with **"umb_"** .is this possible in json.net?

and output will be like:

```
{
        "scbs_currentstatus": "",
          "scbs_primaryissue": "",
           "umbracoMemberComments": "Test",
          "umbracoMemberFailedPasswordAttempts": ""
}
```

using remove i am able to to do it however not all at a time.

```
   result.Property("_umb_id").Remove();
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can parse the string first:

```
var temp =  JArray.Parse(json);
temp.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("_umb_"))
    .ToList() // you should call ToList because you're about to changing the result, which is not possible if it is IEnumerable
    .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove()); // removing unwanted attributes
json = temp.ToString(); // backing result to json
```

**UPDATE** OR:

```
result.Properties()
    .Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("_umb_"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());
```

**UPDATE #2**

You can specify more conditions in `where` clause:

```
.Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("_umb_") && some_other_condition)
```

OR

```
.Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("_umb_") || some_other_condition)
```

Or whatever you need.

Comment: @javed. can we specify more than one condition in it?suppose we dont the fields contains "umbracoMember" in the property.

Answer (score 0):

In case JArray.Parse is not working, you can strongly type your object as follows:

```
var temp = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
temp.Descendants()
 .OfType<JProperty>()
 .Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("_umb_"))
 .ToList() // you should call ToList because you're about to changing the result, which is not possible if it is IEnumerable
 .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove()); // removing unwanted attributes
```

Answer (score -3):

I just ended up deserializing to JObject and recursively looping through that to remove unwanted fields. Here's the function for those interested.

```
private void removeFields(JToken token, string[] fields)
{
JContainer container = token as JContainer;
if (container == null) return;

List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
{
    JProperty p = el as JProperty;
    string propertyName = p.hasOwnProperty(key);

    if (p != null && fields.Contains(p.propertyName) && p.propertyName.substring(0,4) == "_umb" )
    {
        removeList.Add(el);
    }
    removeFields(el, fields);
}

foreach (JToken el in removeList)
{
    el.Remove();
}
}
```