# Parse byte as byte, not string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I receive some JSON from a Java third-party system that contains Avro schemas in JSON format. An example looks like this:

```
{"type":"record", "name":"AvroRecord", "namespace":"Parent.Namespace", "fields": [{"name":"AvroField", "type":"bytes", "default":"\u00FF"}]}
```

I parse this JSON to do some C# code generation. The result would look like this:

```
public partial class AvroRecord
{
    [AvroField(Name = "AvroField", Type = "bytes", DefaultValueText = "ÿ")]
    public byte[] AvroField { get; set; }

    public AvroRecord() {  this.AvroField = new byte[] { 255 }; }
}
```

Eventually, from the C# representation of the schema, I need to *infer* back the original schema. Once I get that inferred schema, it will be sent over to the original system for comparison. That is why I want to keep the original string value for the default value, since I don't know if:

```
{"type":"record", "name":"AvroRecord", "namespace":"Parent.Namespace", "fields": [{"name":"AvroField", "type":"bytes", "default":"\u00FF"}]}
```

and

```
{"type":"record", "name":"AvroRecord", "namespace":"Parent.Namespace", "fields": [{"name":"AvroField", "type":"bytes", "default":"ÿ"}]}
```

will result in an exact match or it will have a problem.

I use JSON.NET to convert from the raw schema as a string to something more useful that I can work with:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(schema);
```

Is there a way in JSON.NET or any other JSON parsing library to control the parsing and copy a value without being parsed? Basically, a way to avoid "\u00FF" becoming "ÿ"

Comment: @JamesThorpe I changed the wording, wasn't very clear. I'd like it "raw"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific properties from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277581/remove-specific-properties-from-json-object)

Comment: Are you in control of the operation that's generating this JSON?  I'd be more inclined to apply a fix there, since the `\u00FF` is part of the JSON spec. If you want the actual string, you should probably escape it before it gets into the JSON.

Comment: @TAHATEMURII I don't think it's the same problem. By the time the parsing has executed, the value is changed. Your link is about changes after the parsing has happened

Comment: Well, `"\u00FF"` *is* `"ÿ"`. Do you mean to use `"\\u00FF"` or maybe `@"\u00FF"`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm not in control of the json, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok please wait I give you solution.

Comment: @Corak I can't change the JSON. If there is a way to revert from "ÿ" to "\u00FF" I may try that, but I wonder if a conversion "back" would work in all cases. The JSON format comes from this Apache specification: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_complex

Comment: This is not a JSON "problem". `\u00FF` is the unicode character code for `ÿ`. You can probably get the numeric value of `ÿ` somehow as hex (`0x00FF`) and "build" `@"\u00FF"` from there. I'd be surprised if there is no built in functionality for that, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Given the docs there, I'd be inclined just to leave it as the char it comes out as, then use [code to convert it to it's byte value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee6e613x(v=vs.110).aspx) where you actually need it - it saves you doing the parse of the underlying string to the numeric value yourself.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [CharUnicodeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.aspx) --- but the important thing to keep in mind is: `\u00FF` and `ÿ` are **the same thing**.

Comment: @JamesThorpe based on your link, something like "String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToInt32(defaultValueText.ToCharArray().First()))" returns "FF", so the conversion is not correct. Am I missing something. defaultValueText contains the value that results from the parsing

Comment: @Corak notice that \u00FF is wrapped in double quotes. If I compare a schema that has "\u00FF" with one that has "ÿ" directly, they won't match. In my opinion, since it is wrapped, Json.NET should not transform the unicode character into anything.

Comment: It _is_ correct.  You can have as many or few leading zeros as you like and it be the same value.  At this point, I'm beginning to think this is looking like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you might want to give a wider context around what it is you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @JamesThorpe schema comparison. Some piece of C# code will ingest the schema, create some class/property attributes. From the "translation", a comparison with the original should be equal. If the value is "interpretated", then the comparison won't succeed.

Comment: @JavierHolguera - I *did* notice that. Notice also that `ÿ` is in double quotes, too. -- `"Hello \u00FF World!"` is the exact same thing as `"Hello ÿ World!"`. -- in other words: `"\u00FF" == "ÿ"` results in `true`.

Comment: Json parses and returns values exactly as they were initially. The problem is that you are inspecting input and output differently: input as *escape sequence*, but output as an unicode string. Use same method to look at content, run debugger and look at `schema`.

Comment: I smell an X/Y problem. Why do you want to see `\u00FF` ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've provided more context in my question. Hopefully, it'll explain why I'm trying to avoid parsing the field value and want it raw instead.

Comment: @JavierHolguera - "I don't know if [A] and [B] will result in an exact match" -- to paraphrase [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): If you have two horses and you want to know if they are equally fast then **race your horses**. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to *guess* if they are equal!

Comment: @Corak nobody is asking you to guess if they will match or not. I'm asking for a way to make sure that after the parsing, the two schemas will be exactly the same, un-escaped. Then, I won't have to worry if they will match.

Comment: @JavierHolguera - The point is: *you* have already all the information you need. You have two JSON objects, one with `"\u00FF"` and one with `"ÿ"`. So parse both and see if they match exactly. My *guess* is: yes, they should absolutely be the exact same thing. -- And whatever else your process is, *you* are the one that best knows that process. So test it with the first one and then with the second one. If both times the result is the same, then for all *your* intends and *your* purposes, they are the same.

Comment: The schema inferred from the C# classes will almost certainly **not** exactly match the schema from which the classes were generated. But: ***Why are you doing this?*** What is the ***purpose***?

Comment: ... btw. you just made me blow some dust of an old JavaDev machine. And it seems to agree, that Java also considers `Objects.equals("\u00FF", "ÿ")` as `true`.