# Remove specific properties from JSON object according to JSON Schema

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

JSON Schema:

```
{
   "title": "Amenities",
   "additionalProperties": false,
   "properties": {
      "Footer": {
         "type": "string",
         "editType": "textarea"
      },
      "RowType": {
         "type": "integer",
         "editType": null
      },
      "answers": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "answer": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "editType": null
                    },
                    "FooterInner": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "editType": "textarea"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
   },
   "type": "object"
}
```

JSON Object:

```
{
   "Footer": "",
   "RowType": 0,
   "answers": [
      {
         "answer": 1,
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter"
      },
      {
         "answer": 2,
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to find properties with `"type=integer"` in JSON Schema and remove those properties from JSON Object.

Expected JSON Object is:

```
{
   "Footer": "",
   "answers": [
      {
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter"
      },
      {
         "FooterInner": "innerfooter2"
      }
   ]
}
```

JSON Schema and JSON Objects may differ, so I need to validate and remove `"type=integer"` properties from any type of JSON Object.

I have searched and could not find something useful, and the main problem is there can be multiple nested elements in JSON.

Might be I need to write recursive iterating function, is there any existing solution?

Comment: have a look at [Remove specific properties from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36277753/2417602) it might help.

Comment: I have already looked at this question, thanks. My problem is JSON schema and JSON objects may differ every time, so I can not deserialize them to any class.

Comment: What you're asking is similar to asking "Can I make my car drive in water?" - Well yes, but you're going to have to do significant modifications, so you may just as well buy a boat rather than a car. JSON Schema isn't designed to do what you're asking here, so you'll have to write the code to do that yourself.

Comment: @Relequestual I don't know how you got this thought, but here my problem is not such a big modification as you said. If you have no proper answer to my question then you don't have to write comment on every json schema related question.

Comment: Apologies if my comment came across wrong. I was trying to express why I feel the answer to your question is "There's no out of the box functionality, you need to write code to do this." I don't feel that sort of answer is always helpful as a SO answer. - I comment on as many JSON Schema questions as I feel may be helpful, given I work on the JSON Schema specification itself.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Now I'm trying to do it with recursive function, I will share my solution once I get it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Instead of searching `"type=integer"` properties in schema I did it in JSON object.

**But,** firstly I validated `JSON object` against the `JSON schema` to be sure that there is no any additional property in `JSON object`.

**1.Step** - Validating JSON Object against JSON Schema:

```
JsonValue loadedSchema = JsonValue.Parse(jsonSchema);
var schema = JsonSchemaFactory.FromJson(loadedSchema);
JsonValue loadedObject = JsonValue.Parse(json);
var schemaValidationResult = schema.Validate(loadedObject);
```

If 1.Step is OK then execute 2.Step

**2.Step** - Remove Integer, Boolean and Float type properties from JSON Object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json =
        @"{
           ""Footer"": ""footer"",
                ""RowType"": 4,
                ""answers"": 
                [
                    {
                        ""answer"": 1,
                        ""FooterInner"": ""innerfooter""
                    },
                    {
                        ""answer"": 2,
                        ""FooterInner"": ""innerfooter2""
                    }
                ]
            }";
    JToken nodeList = JToken.Parse(json);
    List<JTokenType> typesToRemove = new List<JTokenType>(){JTokenType.Boolean, JTokenType.Float, JTokenType.Integer};

    removeFields(nodeList, typesToRemove);

    Console.WriteLine(nodeList.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void removeFields(JToken token, List<JTokenType> typesToRemove)
{
    JContainer container = token as JContainer;
    if (container == null) return;

    List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
    foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
    {
        JProperty p = el as JProperty;
        if (p != null && typesToRemove.Contains(p.Value.Type))
        {
            removeList.Add(el);
        }

        removeFields(el, typesToRemove);
    }

    foreach (JToken el in removeList)
    {
        el.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your example code, is `RowType` and `answer`s removed?

Comment: @Relequestual yes, integer type properties removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options here:

1. Write a custom json converter (see [Custom Deserialization using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net)).
2. Use dynamic objects (Jobjects, JTokens) with json.net.

Comment: Can you share some example code according to my JSON schema and object?

Comment: if you want to use the converter, the link has contains en example (answer). I guess your JsonObject represents the properties object. So you need to use the JsonConverter Attribute.