# How to remove JSON attributes using c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to find a way of removing JSON properties from an arbitrary JSON document.  This is so that I can filter out any data that could be considered sensitive via config.

For example, if I have the below JSON as input, and have an array of property names that I want to filter as ["X","Y"]

```
{
    "X": "some value",
    "Y": "another value",
    "Z": 123.34,
    "Nested": {
        "A": 55,
        "X": true
    },
    "selections": [{
            "blah": 42,
            "X": 55.12
        },
        {
            "blah": 43,
            "X": 66.12
        },
        {
            "blah": 44,
            "X": 77.12
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect the output of the function to be the removal of all X and Y properties whether nested or otherwise:

```
{
    "Z": 123.34,
    "Nested": {
        "A": 55
    },
    "selections": [{
            "blah": 42
        },
        {
            "blah": 43
        },
        {
            "blah": 44
        }
    ]
}
```

Am sure this should be possible with NewtonSoft and/or linq?

Comment: How do you know what sensitive? Will you have classes that also represent the business ideas of these configs?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Have you done any research into it? [Newtonsoft has pretty good documentation with plenty of examples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)...

Comment: Definitely possible, easily accomplished with linq. Try something and we can help. Looking at this post first may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277581/remove-specific-properties-from-json-object